# Count the number of rows that have a specific piece of data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

```
id    Desc      User
1     Print     14
2     Print     7
3     Copy      14
4     Print     19
5     Copy      7
6     Copy      19
7     Attach    19
```

What I'm trying to do is make a column that tells the number of rows per user.

Like this

```
id    User    Count
1     14      2
2     7       2
4     19      3
```

The Point of the report is to show how many activities each user has done.

I need to group by user and get the number of rows within each user.

The problem is, I'm not exactly sure how to do that, is it a `unique` statement somewhere? 
Here's my query so far.

```
Select id       
      ,User
From Table
Group By User
```

I am unsure how to implement the count though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get your result with the [COUNT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) function:

```
SELECT
    MIN(id),
    User,
    COUNT(User) AS Count
FROM
    `table`
GROUP BY
    User
```

Because you can get only one id value per User I assumed from your data that you want the minimum one.